# How can I modify this design on android? Can I put icon left side of other tab items?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-tabs

Is there anyone to help me with making this design with tab layout on the android studio? Can I put icon left side of other tab items?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SiFt.png)

Comment: linear layout with orientation of horizontal. pretty easy. try it out and then report back.

Comment: Try material guidelines for tabs [here](https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html)

Comment: Can I put icon left side of other tab items?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/), probably all possible combinations are well explained.